# How to handle 'Rejected bean name - no URL paths identified' in Spring?

Tags: spring, url, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Application and I get at launch time the following messages:

```
7701 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
7701 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
7701 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
7701 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
7701 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
7701 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'application': no URL paths identified
7701 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor': no URL paths identified
7701 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor': no URL paths identified
7702 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'bookingController': no URL paths identified
```

This is happening for every `@Autowired` I have used in my app.

The only configuration for my application is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I get those messages?

I tried to google after those messages and others said that it may be a conflict  between the default annotation handler and custom annotation handler which I have not defined.

Those are my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.6.1')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34")

    testCompile("junit:junit")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path")
    testCompile("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:0.9.1")
}
```

In my classpath I don't have any settings which may case this.

Comment: I added my dependencies I use at this point.

Comment: You can ignore the messages, if you look at the message you see it is only debug information. The `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` looks at the name of the bean and checks if that name can be converted to a URL. Those message are pure for your information and you can (and should) ignore them as there is nothing you can do about them. You could disable debug logging and then you won't see them. So it has nothing to do with your dependencies or what so ever it is behaving normally.

Comment: Actually I got the same issue (in debug mode logging) for my application: https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As said in the comments, this is a debug message and no actions need to be taken.

For those interested, here are some details:

At startup a [HandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html) is run to determine a mapping between requests and handler objects. The [AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.html) class has a [detectHandlers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.html#detectHandlers--) method that register all handlers found in the current ApplicationContext. When iterating over beans, the beans for which no URL paths are identified, are rejected.

Here is the corresponding [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/bc14c5ba83e1f211628456bbccce7b2531aac58c/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java#L77) :

```
// Take any bean name that we can determine URLs for.
for (String beanName : beanNames) {
    String[] urls = determineUrlsForHandler(beanName);
    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(urls)) {
        // URL paths found: Let's consider it a handler.
        registerHandler(urls, beanName);
    }
    else {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Rejected bean name '" + beanName + "': no URL paths identified");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I saw the same debug messages are was concerned because I mistook it for request mappings.
I am still lost because i don't understand the difference between request mappings (which are found on my controllers) and URL mappings (which the BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping is looking for and which are not found on my controllers) Could you link a documentation that explains the difference? Because i didn't find one.

Comment: I think it's better to ask a new question for this.

Comment: thx, done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158550/what-is-the-difference-between-a-spring-request-mapping-and-url-mapping)