# SPRING MVC - Rejected bean name 'SVGParser': no URL paths identified

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have added a Bean in my AppConfig, and from now i'm getting all Rejected bean name 'xxxxxxxx': no URL paths identified when deploying the application...

I don't know what i did wrong, this is my AppConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("it.beingsmart")

public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public SVGParser parser(){
        return new SVGParser();
    }
```

I added the SVGParser because I autowire it in a controller

```
@Autowired
SVGParser parser;
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: is SVGParser in the package it.beingsmart. If that's true, then I think you can fix this by just removing the bean definition in the AppConfig since it will be scanned by default, provided that it is properly annotated with something like @Component.

Answer (score 0):

The message :

```
Rejected bean name 'xxxxxxxx': no URL paths identified when deploying the application...
```

Is a debug message, which is not problematic at all. See my other answer for more details:

- [How to handle 'Rejected bean name - no URL paths identified' in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581039/how-to-handle-rejected-bean-name-no-url-paths-identified-in-spring/41495726#41495726)